# FlowType wrapping fetch without losing default type annotations

Tags: javascript, node.js, types, flowtype

What I'd like to do is wrap the `fetch` function to deal with some of the `fetch` boilerplate like calling `.json()`.

The problem though is that if I wrap the `fetch` function, in a function with my own annotations, I lose a lot of the type safety because my types will never be as specific as the ones that come with Flow by default.

So I tried to take advantage of the existential types `(*)` and `typeof` to make Flow keep the default annotations

```
// Imported as f because importing as "fetch"
// overwrites all of Flow's default type info about fetch
import f from 'node-fetch'

export const fetchJSON: typeof fetch =
  (url: *, opts: *): * => f(url, opts).then(r => r.json())

export const post: typeof fetchJSON = (url: *, opts: *): * => fetchJSON(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  ...opts
})
```

Unfortunately this gave me some type errors that didn't make much sense

```
 10: export const post: typeof fetchJSON = (url: *, opts: *): * => fetchJSON(url, {
                                                                                  ^ object literal
 11:   method: 'POST',
               ^^^^^^ string. This type is incompatible with
824:     method?: ?MethodType;
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^ null. See lib: /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_22594590/bom.js:824

x.js:10
 10: export const post: typeof fetchJSON = (url: *, opts: *): * => fetchJSON(url, {
                                                                                  ^ object literal
 12:   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object literal. This type is incompatible with
822:     headers?: ?HeadersInit;
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ null. See lib: /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_22594590/bom.js:822

x.js:10
 10: export const post: typeof fetchJSON = (url: *, opts: *): * => fetchJSON(url, {
                                                                                  ^ object literal
 12:   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `Content-Type`. Property not found in
822:     headers?: ?HeadersInit;
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^ Headers. See lib: /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_22594590/bom.js:822


Found 3 errors
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this with a much smaller subset of the bigger problem, and I think I understand the problem now because it's completely unrelated to `fetch` itself.

```
// @flow
const opts: RequestOptions = {}
const test = { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, ...opts }
```

The above causes similar errors, and it's because spreading `opts` into the object might rewrite `'POST'` to `null`, which isn't allowed because it has a `string` type. The solution is to spread into a new object, instead of the existing one. So

```
const test = { ...{ method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }, ...opts }
```

will work.

Comment: do you have a working example of `node-fetch` working with flow type?